# Extra space above DIV unless child text drops to two lines?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that for some reason has extra space above it. In this image the div is at 60% width. Here you can see the elements are not aligned, as the first element has some extra space above.

[image]

When I reduce the width of that div to 49%, which leads to the text being dropped to two lines, the space above the div disappears.

[image]

Here's the code for this part:

```
.fixedMarcomFooter {
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
background-color: $color-white;
text-align: center;
border-top: $px6 solid $color-turquoise-75;

.callUs,
.contactUs,
.liveChat {
  display: inline-block;
  width: $px400;
  color: $color-turquoise-48;
  border-right: $px2 solid $color-turquoise-75;

  &:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: $color-white;
    background-color: $color-turquoise-48;
  }

  i {
    width: $px25;
    margin-right: $px10;

    @include bp-phone {
      width: auto;
      font-size: $phone-px25;
      margin-bottom: $phone-px5;
    }
  }

  a,
  a:hover {
    font-size: $px25;
    line-height: $px30;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $color-turquoise-48;
    padding: $px20 0;

    &:hover {
      color: $color-white;
    }

    .mobileText {
      display: none;

      @include bp-phone {
        display: block;
        font-size: $phone-px10;
      }
    }

    .nonMobileText {
      display: inline-block;

      @include bp-phone {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    @include bp-phone {
      font-size: $phone-px13;
      padding: $phone-px15 0;
      border-right: $phone-px4 solid $color-turquoise-75;

      &:last-child {
        border-right: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my HMTL:

```
      <div className="fixedMarcomFooter">
        <div className="callUs">
          <a href="tel: +99999999999">
            <i className="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true" />
            Call Us (999)-999-9999
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="contactUs">
          <Link to="/contact-us" linkIsMarcom>
            <i className="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true" />
            <span className="nonMobileText">Contact Us</span>
            <span className="mobileText">CONTACT</span>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="liveChat">
          <Link to="/chat" linkIsMarcom>
            <i className="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true" />
            <span className="nonMobileText">Start a Live Chat</span>
            <span className="mobileText">CHAT</span>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Anyone know what's causing this? Also why is it just the first element? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include the variables also and the needed mixins to make it a working example. I was about to try it out but it's to much to figure out what you have and to put the variables ect.

Comment: `vertical-align:top` on the inline-block elements will fix the issue